# How can one make a routine, which uses global variables and blocks on a semaphore, a re-entrant routine?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore, reentrantlock, reentrancy

The routine uses global variables
The routine blocks on a semaphore, sleep
The routine should be re entrant.

Comment: Please share the routine in question.

Comment: It can anything!!My question was, is there a way to make any routine re-entrant assuming if the routine uses global variables and blocks

Comment: Sure,  Why not?  If the function waits on a semaphore, then each recursion will require another unit from the semaphore.  That's just fine, (though I cannot think of much use for it).  Whether the semaphore is global or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Owait - I misread.  'reeentrant', not 'recursive'.  Actually, no different.  A function that signals or waits on a global-or-not semaphore can surely be reentrant and can be entered from multiple threads, interrupted, entered from more threads and still fuction as expected for all the threads.  Note that that applies only to non-interrupt space.  An interrupt-handler cannot wait on a semaphore, but can signal one OK.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!